# ImportError: No module named qgis.core from PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

Trying to load QGIS --

I have a working copy of Python: 2.7.9 --  It looks like QGIS is not finding PyQGIS.

I am aware that this is a problem with the PATH but do not see how to fix it.

```
 > My OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
```

I got a warning when I issued the "apt-get update" command

> W: GPG error: http://qgis.org wheezy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3FF5FFCAD71472C4

When I launch the application ("~> qgis") I get two warnings

> Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/share/qgis/i18n//qgis_en_US]
>
> Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]

and a window with the following info:

> Couldn't load PyQGIS.
>
> Python support will be disabled.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in
>
> ImportError: No module named qgis.core
>
> Python version:
>   2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:26:58) 
>   [GCC 4.7.2]
>
> QGIS version:
>   2.10.0-Pisa 'Pisa', exported
>
> Python path:
>   ['/usr/share/qgis/python', u'/home/cjohnson/.qgis2/python', u'/home/cjohnson/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat-0.9.5.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/VTK-6.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/runipy-0.1.1-py2.7.egg']

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is with your old Debian version (wheezy). You should upgrade to jessie.

This is my **/etc/apt/sources.list** (including QGIS repository):

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

#QGIS
deb     http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
```

After saving, in bash console as root:

```
wget -O - http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2015.gpg.key | gpg --import
gpg --fingerprint 3FF5FFCAD71472C4  #to avoid GPG error
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

My upgrading involved more than 3000 files several months ago and it was successfully (but I do not guarantee the same in your system). You have to wait a while (more than 1 hour).

After upgrading you should have the problem solved.